# IPv6 built-in security?

Tags: ipv6, security

At one time IPv6 was supposed to have built-in security. I don't know how it was supposed to be implemented, but my guess is that perhaps, if your stack and application supported it, you could simply click a button which would secure the connection in an opportunistic way, or connect securely but fall back to insecure if not supported, similar to how the Philip Zimmerman's zfone works.

What happened to this? Is it in use, or is it an optional feature, which could be implemented down the road? Is it a standard, and what is the name of it?

Comment: I use the mobile app and I don't see a way to mark one. I want to mark Ricky beams answer as its the most complete one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be honest, it's a bit of a botched job. People (including Big Name Vendors) still look at IPSec as a means of tunneling. In IPv6, the IPSec headers were meant to allow any socket from any application to be encrypted. The only system I'm aware of doing this is [Cisco's OSPFv3 security](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/ipv6/command/reference/ipv6_book/ipv6_08.html#wp2228381).

Answer (score 3):

The security bit you're referring to is [IPsec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec).

It exists, is in use, and is pretty cool. But it hasn't yet been applied to all or lots of traffic as was originally dreamed.

From [the WP article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec#Standards_status):

> IPsec was developed in conjunction with IPv6 and was originally required to be supported by all standards-compliant implementations of IPv6 before RFC 6434 made it only a recommendation. IPsec is also optional for IPv4 implementations. IPsec is most commonly used to secure IPv4 traffic.